# How can i solve that problem with my Bot?

Tags: api, calendar, bots, telegram, scheduler

i got a problem with my Telegram Bot.
I start by saying that's my first time i try to program a bot and i don't know really well Python language. I'm still studying at University and we are just doing C++.
I never used Google APIs before and i really dont know how to solve that problem.
I've looked around in Google but unfortunatly i was not able to solve that. The Telegram Bot is hosted by heroku.com, i don't know if that influence on the proper working of the Bot.
That's my repo with all the files of the telegram bot. [My repo](https://github.com/Bakk-f4/Telegram-Booking-Bot/tree/master).
In addition of those files i've got my api_key.py and the credentials.json files.

So, now it's time to talk about the problem.
My Telegram Bot is a fork from GitHub from the project of [kaikiat](https://github.com/kaikiat/telegram-scheduler-bot).
I've done all the steps into the guide at the link in the description.

The fact is, it works until someone dont send the email for the verification of it and the bot should save the schedule into the Calendar.
When the bot try to save the appointment i get this error.

this is the error i encouter when the bot try to save the schedule in the Google Calendar:

"Errore 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:47354/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs, visit: [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/${your_client_id}?project=${your_project_number}"](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/$%7Byour_client_id%7D?project=$%7Byour_project_number%7D%22)

Any advice to solve that problem?
If there are more information i have to provide, fell free to ask.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Comment: Why you're writing own telegram client? Just use [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) framework. It already has proper methods to talk with Telegram. I'm not sure, but for Google you can find similar framework. So your code become readable and simple.

Comment: Thanks you a lot for your answer! May i ask where i can find a good guide how to use this Aiogram framework?

Comment: Just open my link and look in `/examples` folder :)

Comment: unfortunatly thats not at my level of programming :( need to learn more things before i start programming in other languages... or i got a tutorial/guide or at the moment im not able to do that.. :(

Comment: Just start with [echo-bot](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/echo_bot.py). 50 lines of code!

Comment: thank you a lot for your help! :) ill do my best ahah